# Asymptotic behaviour of an oscillating integral with Bessel functions

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, bessel-functions

I'm interested in the following integral:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^6}{64} \int_0^\infty du \  u^5 J_0(x u) \frac{K_1(u)}{I_1(u)}$$

where $J_0$ is a Bessel function of the first kind and $K_1, I_1$ are modified Bessel functions. I want to understand the behaviour of this integral at large $x$. (This is a Hankel transform which arose in the context of a two-dimensional Fourier transform.)

I evaluated it numerically in Mathematica up to $x = 8$ and it seems that

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = -1$$

with $1 + f(x)$ decaying exponentially in $x$. I'd like to prove this statement, but I don't know how.

I don't think the stationary phase approximation will work because for large $u$ the Bessel function oscillates like $\cos(xu - \pi/4)$, which doesn't have a point of stationary phase.

With the change of variable $v = x u$, the integral takes the form

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{64} \int_0^\infty dv \ v^5 J_0(v) \frac{K_1(v/x)}{I_1(v/x)} .
$$

I thought I could use the small-argument expansion of the modified Bessel function $K_1, I_1$, but they are not useful since the argument becomes arbitrarily large as $v \rightarrow \infty$.

How can I derive the large $x$ behaviour of this integral?

Comment: You may consider this paper: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82476688.pdf

Comment: It might be much easier to handle the Fourier transform directly, what was the initial Fourier transform ?